# Reading and parsing JSON with ijson

Tags: python, json, ijson

I have some big json files with the following structure:

```json
[
  {
    "url": "",
    "publishedDate": "",
    "modifiedDate": "",
    "title": "",
    "summary": "",
    "content": "",
    "language": "",
    "section": "",
    "tags": [],
    "authors": []
  },
  {
    "url": "",
    "publishedDate": "",
    "modifiedDate": "",
    "title": "",
    "summary": "",
    "content": "",
    "language": "",
    "section": "",
    "tags": [],
    "authors": []
  },
  ...
]
```

But serializing this big JSONs with the default python `json` library ends up consuming too much memory so I've searched for other alternatives. One of such is `ijson` which, is supposed to consume only the same amount in memory as the file size itself.

Problem is, I don't know how to use it (I'm new to python from a java perspective) and most tutorials I've found don't parse jsons like the one above. How can I make ijson yield `dictionaries` for each item in the json's list?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked [the `ijson` documentation](https://pypi.org/project/ijson/#high-level-interfaces)? There's an example that's quite similar to what you are trying to do here.

Comment: Yes, I've seen the `kvitems` method but wasn't sure how to use it for this json. Thanks still.